# D3.js Selecting min/max value from an array of arrays (nesting d3.extent)

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have a bit of code that takes the values of the  elements in a column and places them into an array:

```
var someArray = new Array(rows.selectAll("td").filter(function(d,i)
    {
        if(i==2) //index of the cells in the rows where I retrieve the data  
        {
            return (d3.select(this))
        }
    }));
```

^ creates an array of array[1]s that have the value of the cell in the  element such as "2.6" or "5.4"

When I try to use:

```
console.log(d3.min(someArray));
```

I get [Array[1], Array[1], Array[1],...] whereas what I need returned is the lowest, and then largest value amongst those arrays (this will be used in d3.scale.linear().domain([The minimum value,The maximum value])

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to nest the calls:

```
var min = d3.min(arrayOfArrays, function(d) { return d3.min(d); });
```

<strike>To get both max and min at the same time, use `d3.extent()`:</strike>

```
// extent[0] == min, extent[1] == max
var extent = d3.extent(arrayOfArrays, function(d) { return d3.extent(d); });
```

Unfortunately you can't get the extent in the nested case -- you'll have to do min and max separately.

Comment: When I try

`console.log(d3.extent(arrayOfArrays, function(d){return d3.extent(d); })); `

it returns [Array[2], Array[2]], each containing the same data (in this case "2.6", the lowest value

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right that this doesn't actually work in the nested case. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For a nested version of `d3.extend`, a little ES6 goodness and the possibility to have an `accessor` you can use the following:

```
function nestedExtent(data, accessor) {
  return data.reduce(([extentMin, extentMax], d) => {
    const [min, max] = extent(d, accessor);

    return [
      Math.min(extentMin, min),
      Math.max(extentMax, max),
    ];
  }, [Infinity, -Infinity]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way to nest `d3.extent` and I couldn't find one, so I resorted to figuring it out for myself and this is what I came up with...

```
var extent = d3.extent(arrayOfArrays.reduce(function(m,d){return m.concat(d)},[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based off of @Johnny answer for those of us not fortunate enough to be using ES6:

```
function nestedExtent(data, accessor) {

  return data.reduce( function ( prevArr, currArr) {
    var extentArr = d3.extent([currArr], accessor);

    return [
      Math.min(prevArr[0], extentArr[0]),
      Math.max(prevArr[1], extentArr[1])
    ];

  }, [Infinity, -Infinity] );
}
```

Example:

```
var mydata = [4, 6, -2, 42, 17];

nestedExtent( mydata , function(d) { return d; });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have data which is an array of arrays, I use a bit different way with mixture of [Cool Blue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232033/826690) solution.
My data is like

```
[[{
  "timestamp": 44299.46625605324,
  "dateTime": "2021-04-13T11:11:24.5237792Z",
  "value": 9.92,
  "status": 0
},
{
  "timestamp": 44299.466267627315,
  "dateTime": "2021-04-13T11:11:25.5237792Z",
  "value": 3.92,
  "status": 0
},],[{
  "timestamp": 44299.46625605324,
  "dateTime": "2021-04-13T11:11:24.5237792Z",
  "value": 9.92,
  "status": 0
},
{
  "timestamp": 44299.466267627315,
  "dateTime": "2021-04-13T11:11:25.5237792Z",
  "value": 3.92,
  "status": 0
},]]
```

and I try to use timescale in x axis and use dateTime property to get the scale domain.

```
d3.extent(data.reduce(function(m,d){
                            return m.concat(d3.extent(d, d => new Date(d.dateTime).valueOf()))
                        },[]))
```